# how to turn off a samsung A10 that keeps rebooting?

Tags: samsung

I have had my Samsung A10 for about 2 years now. A few days ago it restarted by itself and got stuck in Upload Mode: It was showing a screen with two options: connecting to PC and Rebooting the device. A message was displayed at the bottom of the page saying something about missing bootloader. (I don't remember the exact message). After rebooting the phone as guided in that page (press and hold the Volume Down and Power buttons), it now keeps rebooting and does not load any further than displaying the android logo.

I googled about it and tried to do some factory reset (press and hold Volume Up and Power buttons) but it didn't help, because the phone reboots fast and doesn't allow me to choose the factory reset option or any other option in the page.

I can't even trun the phone off. It drives me crazy. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a behavior change when you connect the phone to a charger?

Comment: @Robert Not at all, but It does charge and when connecting it to a computer it makes connection sound.